# Can not pick up the element using python selenium binding from a website for unknown reasons

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is the website "https://agta.org/directory/", no matter what i tried i was not able to click the search button, i gave a delay clicked the button manually hoping for the script to pick up elements at the next stage, but it did not worked as well, "**find_element_by_xpath**" is returning empty objects. I can't understand why is it happening that way when the x path is 100% accurate. I have used similar script for other site but never had any problem.

For clicking the search button i used java script, action chains as well, still failed.

```
#using selenium
#search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='DLGButton']").click()
#using js
#driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('DLGButton')[0].click()")
```

Here is my detailed code:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'D:\chromedriver.exe')

url='https://agta.org/directory/'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='DLGButton']").click()    
time.sleep(10)

listings=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-md-3']//a")
print(listings)
check=1
while(check==1):
    index=1
    for l in listings:
        l=driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='col-md-3']//a)[{}]".format(index)).get_attribute('href').strip()
        print(l)
        index=index+1
    try:
        clickNext=find_element_by_xpath("(//*[contains(text(), 'Next')])[1]").click()
        time.sleep()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        check=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search button is in the frame. So you should switch the frame first.

[image]

I modify your code and click Search Button successfully.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url='https://agta.org/directory/'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
# find the frame
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='directory_iframe']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
# wait element to be clickable
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='DLGButton']")))
# check button can be found
print(search.get_attribute("value"))
# Scroll the page to show this button (or it will fail to click)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", search)
search.click()
```

And you can use Explicit Waits instead of time.sleep()

Ex: To confirm the presence of the element within the DOM Tree.

```
frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located
((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='directory_iframe']")))
```

Reference: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thank you very much it works for the search button, can you please have a look why is it not working inside where the listings are displayed, i am changing the frame there as well. //div[@class='container-fluid outer page_header']//ifram

Comment: clicking the next page button.

Comment: @JawadAhmadKhan Because you have already switch into the frame, you won't change again.